# UICollectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath crash ios 10

Tags: crash

I got this error on iOS 10, but it works fine both on iOS 11 and iOS 9.

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 5 beyond bounds [0 .. 4]'

Here is my code:

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)

print(indexPath.row) // 5
//here is the problem. I got 6 items in my datasource but looks like collectionView still consider it's only 5.
print(collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: 0)) // 6

if indexPath.row < collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: 0) {
    collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
}
```

I've checked the numberOfItems before I call scrollToItem, but still got crash. Kind of weird, has anyone encountered this problem before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It also happened to me. It seems that Apple introduced some modifications on iOS10 that forces to manually invalidateLayout() after reloading the data. This wasn't needed on iOS9 and it also not needed on iOS11. So, either they changed their mind or it was a bug :)

Just call `invalidateLayout()` to avoid the crash, like this:

```
self.collectionView.reloadData()
self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout() // Fix iOS10 crash
```

Comment: Hmm, that makes sense. Thanks, I'll try it later.

Comment: Solved my problem, thanks ! Tested in iOS 10.3.1 (iOS 11 don't need it but work fine with it)